# Is it OK to use the BSON Timestamp datatype?

Tags: mongodb, bson

According to the documentation:

> The BSON timestamp type is for *internal* MongoDB use.

[Ref.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html#timestamps)

Is this implying that I shouldn't use it or just advising that it's not a `BsonDate`?

(My question is, will I get shouted at for using it?)

Comment: The BSON Timestamp type is mainly intended for internal use by the MongoDB replication system and is documented for completeness. A general caveat on BSON types "for internal use" is they are not expected to be extensively supported by drivers or server features (for example: timestamps cannot be used with [Time-to-Live indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) or [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)). Server code may also make assumptions about how internal field types like Timestamp should be treated.

Comment: The MongoDB documentation is strongly suggesting that you instead use the BSON Date type to avoid potential issues. What is your use case for the timestamp?

Comment: @Stennie Actually, no use now.  I wanted to use it to order documents and have Mongo set the time.  I've attacked it a  different way now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BSON Timestamp type is mainly intended for internal use by the MongoDB replication system and is documented for completeness.

A general caveat on BSON types "for internal use" is that they are not expected to be extensively supported by drivers or server features. For example, BSON Timestamps cannot be used with [Time-to-Live indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) or [Date Aggregation Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/). MongoDB server code may also make assumptions about how internal field types like Timestamp should be treated, and possibly introduce behavioural changes to support expected internal use cases.

> Is this implying that I shouldn't use it or just advising that it's not a BsonDate?

The MongoDB documentation is strongly implying that you use the BSON Date type for your application development to avoid potential issues.

There may be cases where you need to work with Timestamp values (for example, if you wanted to develop a script to work with timestamps in a MongoDB [replica set oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/)), but you should avoid relying on the BSON Timestamp type or behaviour for your own use cases.